# Apostrophe - Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, apostrophe-cms, apostrophe

Is it possible to deploy Apostrophe on Azure? If so, is there any form of documentation? I have looked around and seen no one talk about apostrophe on azure. I know one major downfall of trying to deploy apostrophe on azure is that ImageMagick is not supported on azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible. People have discussed doing it in the [Apostrophe Discord chat](http://chat.apostrophecms.com/). There is not documentation about Azure specifically, but existing deployment documentation touches on concepts that should apply to Azure.